# most current date for each ID

Tags: mysql

I am trying to pull the list of ID's with the latest date with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.ID,
    A.Price,
    A.Date
FROM
    shop A
WHERE
    A.ID <> '0'
    AND A.Price > '0'
```

Example output:

```
ID  Price     Date
1   2.2     2017-03-12
1   1.5     2017-04-16
2   2.0     2016-03-12
2   1.1     2017-03-12
3   5.0     2017-01-23
4   3.5     2016-08-05
```

But the following is the desired output:

```
ID  Price     Date
1   1.5     2017-04-16
2   1.1     2017-03-12
3   5.0     2017-01-23
4   3.5     2016-08-05
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way of approaching this without using analytic functions would be to join `shop` to a subquery which identifies the latest record for each `ID`.

```
SELECT s1.*
FROM shop s1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, MAX(Date) AS max_date
    FROM shop
    WHERE ID <> 0 AND Price > 0    -- not sure about this condition
    GROUP BY ID
) s2
    ON s1.ID   = s2.ID AND
       s1.Date = s2.max_date
```

Comment: Wouldnt it work the same without a joined sub query? still grouping by id and having MAX(date) as one of the select options?

Comment: No, I don't imagine what you have in mind would work.  Your deleted answer also will not work.